# C++ Classes in different files issue

Tags: c++

I have a slight problem with my new program. I made a class file, and it all went nice and cozy UNTIL!
I get this!

C:\Code Block Projects\Not so Advanced Calculator\Calcu.cpp|5|error: expected                              lified-id before '{' token|

In codeblocks 12.11;

My Calcu.h file:

```
 #ifndef CALCU_H
 #define CALCU_H


class Calcu
{
    public:
        Calcu();
};

#endif // CALCU_H
```

My Calcu.cpp class file:

```
    #include "Calcu.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
Calcu{
    Calcu(){}
    public:
    void setNumbers(int x, int y){ no1=x, no2=y; }
    int getAddition() {return no1+no2;}
    int getSubstraction() {return no1-no2;}
    int getDivision() {return no1/no2;}
    int getMultiplication() {return no1*no2;}
    int getExponent(){ return no1**no2; }
private:
    int no1, no2;
};
```

And my main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <Calcul.h>
using namespace std;

void function_calculator()
{
        Calcu calcul;
    int noI, noII; char operation;
    cout << "Welcome to a more advanced and optimized calculator. ©UnityInc." << endl;
    cout << "Please insert your desired numbers. First number should be carefully selected if you wish to raise to the exponent.";
    cin>>noI;
    cout<<"Great, now insert your other number: ";
    cin>>noII;
    calcu.setNumbers(noI, noII);
    cout<<"Very well, what kind of operation would you like? +, -, *, / or exponantiation(type **): ";
    cin>>operation;
    if(operation=='+')
        calcul.getAddition();
    else if(operation=='-')
        calcul.getSubstraction();
    else if(operation=='/')
        calcul.getDivision();
    else if(operation=='*')
        calcul.getMultiplication();
    else if(operation=='**')
        calcul.getExponent();
    else
        return function_calculator;

}

int main()
{
    function_calculator;
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems: One is in the source file `Calcu.cpp` where the error message is about. You're missing a `class` or `struct` before `Calcu`.

The other problem is that you try to redefine the class in the source file. You should put the full definition in the header file, and the implementation of the methods in the source file.

And as mentioned by WhozCraig in a comment, solving the second problem also solves the first.

Comment: +1, and first problem is made irrelevant if the second problem is addressed.

Answer (score 1):

here is some recommendation based on your question:

- You should not define `Calcu` twice in your  `Calcu.cpp` and `Calcu.h`. You should arrange your code that  the header file only have the members and interface declaration of the class, and put all the implementations in the `Calcu.cpp` file.

  - For the `#include <header.h>`  statement in the code, the C++ preprocessor will only expand the header file at that point. So after expansion, your Calcu.cpp will have two definition of `class Calcu` which will have problem.
- In `getExponent()`, C++ does not support `**` operator. You should use a math library. (and can not overload `**` operator, since C++ only support exist operator overload )

Answer (score 0):

My Calcu.h file:

```
 #ifndef CALCU_H
 #define CALCU_H


class Calcu
{
    public:
        Calcu(){}

    void setNumbers(int x, int y){ no1=x, no2=y; }
    int getAddition() {return no1+no2;}
    int getSubstraction() {return no1-no2;}
    int getDivision() {return no1/no2;}
    int getMultiplication() {return no1*no2;}
    int getExponent(){ return //your exponent; }
private:
    int no1, no2;
};

#endif // CALCU_H
```

My Calcu.cpp class file:

```
#include "Calcu.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

And my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Calcul.h>
using namespace std;

void function_calculator()
{
//...
}

int main()
{
    function_calculator();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped alot! And thanks again for the step by step cf16 :3